# FastScroller when giving APK

Tags: android, debugging, apk, release

I have a problem when I want to create an APK for release.
I searched a lot but I did not find my answer. So if you can help I really appreciate.
please help me...

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
Warning:android.support.v7.widget.FastScroller: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.widget.FastScroller$State
Warning:android.support.v7.widget.FastScroller: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.widget.FastScroller$DragState
Warning:android.support.v7.widget.FastScroller: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.widget.FastScroller$AnimationState
Warning:android.support.v7.widget.FastScroller: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.widget.FastScroller$State
Warning:there were 4 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
```

> Job failed, see logs for details
>   Information:BUILD FAILED in 1m 42s
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:6 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Answer (score 0):

Please, remove your `project_name/gradle` directory, set `Project structure\Project\Gradle version`, and then Run/Make/Generate your APK. Deletion of `build` and `app/build` did not solved this problem in my case, for example.